# Log all nginx signals (KILL, WINCH, HUP etc)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, signals

I have an nginx v1.21 server running on Ubuntu. My goal is to make sure I have some way of checking when it reloads its configurations (`HUP`) and when it restarts (`USR2`). How can I make nginx log these signals into syslog or anywhere else?

Comment: The question title mentions KILL.  You cannot do anything with a KILL signal.  Period.  You can have a parent process detect that a child is KILLed, so you can get logging from the parent, but a process can not respond to a KILL in any way.   Often  people are sloppy and they intend to say "TERM" when they say "KILL", but you must remember that a process does not have an opportunity to take any action in response to a SIGKILL.